# Specifying vmImage for hosted agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline job in which I need the host machine to have BLAS and LAPACK installed. As I see it, I have three options:

- Install BLAS/LAPACK at each build (this is time-consuming) (actually, I might not even have authorization to do this)
- Install BLAS/LAPACK to a Docker container, and use this as base for job (this gives other compatability issues, however)
- Install BLAS/LAPACK to the vmImage that is basis for the job

Therefore: **Is it possible to extend/modify/specify the vmImage for *hosted* agents?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Hosted Agents can not be configured or changed, to Microsot have a purpose VM for them and each build you got a new clean machine.

If you don't want to install BLAS/LAPACK in each build you should consider use your own [self hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install) that have the tools installed, or use the docker container with those tools and do the build there (but you can have another issues, like you mentioned).